# How to get fontawesome to work on an Azure web pages deployment?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, azure, fonts, font-awesome

We are using Twitter Bootstrap and [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome) for icon support.

When deploying to one of our IIS servers I need to add MIME support.

When deploying to Azure, it doesn't look like I have this ability, so now my icons aren't showing up because it doesn't seem to know how to use the font.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just add the following to the web.config ...

```xml
<system.webServer>    
   <staticContent>
       <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
       <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
       <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been fighting this for two days now!

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but still it doesn't work. Although the MIME types on the server side do get updated with the Local definitions.

Comment: where is web.config located?

Comment: @fscore It is located in the root folder of your site. The same place you would be storing an index.html file.

Comment: The woff line should be `<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />`

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

This answer is now unnecessary due to recent changes in the [FontAwesome](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome/) nuget package.

---

In addition to the solution described in the accepted answer, I noticed that the fonts in my project were in ~/Content/fonts, but the site was looking for the fonts in /fonts on Azure.

As a workaround, I copied the font files to ~/fonts (making sure the Build Action was set to `Content` for all) and all is good in the cloud.

Comment: The original answer above is required - about the web.config changes. But this answer also helped set me in the right direction. I didn't want to publish my fonts in a different location (~/fonts) so I just separated fontawesome into its own bundle with a lower level path /Content/fonts/bundle ... like this: 

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fonts/bundle").Include("~/Content/fontawesome/font-awesome.css"));

Comment: this solution works. For some reason font-awesome was looking for the font folder in the root even tho the url(../) inside font-awesome.css is looking for the relative font folder inside font-awesome directory

Answer (score 1):

After doing the above, and if it still doesn't work, check the file for the font-awesome.css in your theme folder's css folder.

There is a URL linking the font-awesome files. Make sure it points to the folder with the font files from your new domain pointing to your Azure site, i.e enter the full URL instead of `../font/..`.