# fonts not recognized on azure through github

Tags: github, fonts, azure-web-app-service, web-development-server

I am uploading my changes into github and my site can be seen on azure. I can see my fonts being applied on my local workspace but not on the url. do you know why?

I checked my github and fonts are uploaded there but cannot be regognized on website.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309138/how-to-get-fontawesome-to-work-on-an-azure-web-pages-deployment

Comment: Once I had to restart the web-site after adding the fonts. Try it.

Comment: @ahmelsayed do you know where web.config is located?

Comment: it should be in the root of your site. right under `wwwroot\` if you don't have one, just create a file named `web.config` and put this in it https://gist.github.com/ahmelsayed/699136e0177c2d4a0ca1#file-web-config